How to Automatically Send a WhatsApp Message When a User Opens a WA Chat Using Twilio
I recently faced a challenge where I needed to automatically send a message from a WhatsApp bot as soon as a user opens the chat via link, without requiring the user to send any initial message.
How to achieve it? I thought this wasn't possible but GuideGeek did it. Check this - https://api.whatsapp.com/message/Z3KZIFAXNBROL1?autoload=1&app_absent=0
Please help on creating a flow like this.
Thanks
Tried Twilio function and Studio, maybe not right way.

I'm not sure if the link does what you describe. When I click it, it opens a new WA conversation with a contact but it doesn't send a message. You can suffix links this ?text=Hello and then this text would be prefilled for the user to send. But in either case, the user will send the first message

There is a concept called business initiated session that does what you describe but I don't see this in the link you posted

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Thanks guys. I found the solution at Facebook WA. I don't think so Twilio helped or maybe I didn't try enough with Twilio - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/phone-numbers/conversational-components/

If I understand what you need, you can use Twilio's Content API functionality.
With this API, you will be able to send a message with a template pre-approved by Twilio/Meta to your client's WhatsApp number.
To learn more about the Content API and how to trigger, visit: https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/create-and-send-your-first-content-api-template
